# What is the recommended way to install Node.js, nvm and npm on MacOS X?

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, homebrew, nvm

I am trying to use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) as much as possible. What's the recommended way to install [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/), [`nvm`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) and [npm](https://www.npmjs.com) on MacOS X?

Comment: It should be noted that although you asked to use homebrew. Using homebrew to install nvm is not recommended  From https://github.com/creationix/nvm/ "Homebrew installation is not supported. If you have issues with homebrew-installed nvm, please brew uninstall it, and install it using the instructions below, before filing an issue."

Comment: 2022 Solution - use `nvm` not `brew`. But, use `brew` to install `nvm`.

Answer (score 300, accepted):

1. Using `homebrew` install `nvm`:

   ```
   brew update
   brew install nvm
   source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh
   ```

   Add the last command to the `.profile`, `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` file to not run it again on every terminal start. So for example to add it to the `.profile` run:

   ```
   echo "source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh" >> ~/.profile
   ```

   If you have trouble with installing `nvm` using `brew` you can install it manually (see [here](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#install-script))
2. Using `nvm` install `node` or `iojs` (you can install any version you want):

   ```
   nvm install 0.10
   # or
   nvm install iojs-1.2.0
   ```
3. `npm` is shipping with `node` (or `iojs`), so it will be available after installing `node` (or `iojs`). You may want to upgrade it to the latest version:

   ```
   $ npm install -g npm@latest
   ```

   **UPD** Previous version was <s>`npm update -g npm`</s>. Thanks to @Metallica for pointing to the correct way (look at the comment bellow).
4. Using `npm` install `ionic`:

   ```
   npm install -g ionic
   ```
5. What about `ngCordova`: you can install it using `npm` or `bower`. I don't know what variant is more fit for you, it depends on the package manager you want to use for the client side. So I'll describe them both:

   1. **Using `npm`**: Go to your project folder and install `ng-cordova` in it:

      ```
      npm install --save ng-cordova
      ```
   2. **Using `bower`**: Install bower:

      ```
       npm install -g bower
      ```

      And then go to your project folder and install `ngCordova` in it:

      ```
       bower install --save ngCordova
      ```

**PS**

1. Some commands may require superuser privilege
2. Short variant of `npm install some_module` is `npm i some_module`

Comment: If you update npm itself, **do NOT use the npm update command.**
The upstream-recommended way to update npm is: `npm install -g npm@latest` (from `brew info node`, and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284634/upgrade-nodejs-to-the-latest-version-on-mac-os) )

Comment: I followed these steps on a new mac, but each time I restart the terminal, `node -v` returns `node: command not found`. So I do again `nvm install node` and it says `v0.12.2 is already installed.
Now using node v0.12.2 (npm v2.7.4)`. And then `node -v` returns `v0.12.2`. Same thing with iojs. What's happening here? thanks

Comment: I understand this is nvm default behavior: github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/714#issuecomment-89720100. To set a default version when a terminal window starts do: `nvm alias default node` or `nvm alias default iojs`

Comment: I did all this, but for me the npm command is only available after I do: `nvm install iojs`. If I restart the terminal, it is not available anymore. And I get:
`env: node: No such file or directory`

Comment: Just want to mention the the ```brew install nvm``` info screen post install also indicates that you should add ```export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm``` to the shell initialization script. The description in the answer above doesn't.

Comment: From the current brew nvm install: "Please note that upstream has asked us to make explicit managing nvm via Homebrew is unsupported by them ..." -> So probably the right answer is to not use brew for nvm / node.js / io.js.

Comment: I was receiving the error message "nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option".  according to this site (https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/855#issue-109279804) , NVM is not compatible with Homebrew.  I "brew uninstalled nvm" and installed nvm via the CURL command and now the error message is gone.

Comment: I used nvm via brew for a while but got the "upstream... explicit... unsupported" message too. NVM docs explicitly say "Homebrew installation is not supported. If you have issues with homebrew-installed nvm, please brew uninstall it, and install it using the instructions below, before filing an issue." So this probably shouldn't be the accepted answer anymore. I just started using n which works.

Comment: The latest brew instructions on nvm uses '. "/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh"' instead of 'source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh'.

Comment: Current NVM version (v0.33.2) DOES NOT support homebrew installation: See: https://github.com/creationix/nvm/tree/v0.33.2#installation

Comment: obviously nvm is overcomplicated, better look at answer with `n` below, which worked just great for me

Answer (score 121):

## Use `nvm` to install Node.js, not Homebrew

In most of the answers, the recommended way to install `nvm` is to use Homebrew.

### Don't do this.

On `nvm`'s [Github Readme](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/master/README.md#:%7E:text=Homebrew%20installation%20is%20not%20supported.) is clearly says:

> Homebrew installation is not supported. If you have issues with homebrew-installed `nvm`, please `brew uninstall` it, and install it using the instructions below, before filing an issue.

Use the following method instead

```sh
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
```

The script clones the nvm repository to `~/.nvm` and adds the source line to your profile (`~/.bash_profile`, `~/.zshrc`, `~/.profile`, or `~/.bashrc`).

And then use `nvm` to install node. For example to install latest LTS version do:

```sh
nvm install 16
```

Clean and hassle free. It will set this as your default Node.js version as well so you should be all set.

Comment: I think you could also `nvm install --lts` to get the latest LTS

Comment: Thank you for bringing this up, I went down a horrible rabbit hole with nvm and homebrew and just emerged...

Comment: Good answer! After a lot of reading (node installs can be a minefield), I just brew uninstalled node, cleaned everything out and used nvm to install node on Mojave 10.14.4: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55735701/123033

Comment: what's the bes way to install "nvm" ?

Comment: The title is misleading. Yes, we should not use brew to install nvm. But that doesn't mean we should use nvm over brew to install node. Some people prefer brew over nvm if they only care about the latest version of each LTS version.

Answer (score 14):

I'm using n (Node version management)

You can install it in two ways

```
brew install n
```

or

```
npm install -g n
```

You can switch between different version of node and io. Here's an example from my current env when I call n without params:

```
$ n

  io/3.3.1
  node/0.12.7
  node/4.0.0
  node/5.0.0
ο node/5.10.1
```

Comment: You can add a third way to install which is painless and leaves a handy uninstall utility if you need it - https://github.com/mklement0/n-install

This method is suggested in the n docs at https://github.com/tj/n

Comment: It should also be mentioned that if you're planning to run different node versions for different projects simultaneously (like in 2 different terminal windows) nvm is a better choice, because it switches just the paths to node in each session.

Answer (score 13):

I'm super late to this but I didn't like the other answers

### Installing Homebrew

**For brew** run

```
"$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

### Installing node & npm

You **SHOULD NOT** use `brew` to install **node** and **npm**.

I've seen a few places suggested that you should use Homebrew to install Node (like alexpods answer and in this [Team Treehouse blog Post](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/install-node-js-npm-mac)) but installing this way you're more prone to run into issues as `npm` and `brew` are both **package managers** and you should have a **package manager** manage another **package manager** this leads to problems, like this bug offical **npm** issues [Error: Refusing to delete: /usr/local/bin/npm](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3794) or this [Can't uninstall npm module on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33015001/cant-uninstall-npm-module-on-osx)

You can read more on the topic in DanHerbert's post  [Fixing npm On Mac OS X for Homebrew Users](https://gist.github.com/DanHerbert/9520689), where he goes on to say

> Also, using the Homebrew installation of npm will require you to use sudo when installing global packages. Since one of the core ideas behind Homebrew is that apps can be installed without giving them root access, this is a bad idea.

### For Everything else

I'd use npm; but you really should just follow the install instruction for each modules following the directions on there website as they will be more aware of any issue or bug they have than anyone else

Comment: So you suggest just installing it from their download?

Answer (score 7):

If you have previously installed node using brew, then you will have a bunch of extra files that you should clean up before installing node "the right way".  Plus, I had to add a few settings to my startup script to make things work smoothly.

I wrote a script to make this easy.

```
# filename:  install-nvm-npm-node
# author:    Lex Sheehan
# purpose:   To cleanly install NVM, NODE and NPM
# dependencies:  brew

NOW=$(date +%x\ %H:%M:%S)
CR=$'\n'
REV=$(tput rev)
OFF=$(tput sgr0)
BACKUP_DIR=$HOME/backups/nvm-npm-bower-caches/$NOW
MY_NAME=$(basename $0)
NODE_VER_TO_INSTALL=$1
if [ "$NODE_VER_TO_INSTALL" == "" ]; then
    NODE_VER_TO_INSTALL=v0.12.2
fi
if [ "`echo "$NODE_VER_TO_INSTALL" | cut -c1-1`" != "v" ]; then
    echo """$CR""Usage:   $ $MY_NAME <NODE_VERSION_TO_INSALL>"
    echo "Example: $ $MY_NAME v0.12.1"
    echo "Example: $ $MY_NAME $CR"
    exit 1
fi
echo """$CR""First, run:  $ brew update"
echo "Likely, you'll need to do what it suggests."
echo "Likely, you'll need to run: $ brew update$CR"
echo "To install latest node version, run the following command to get the latest version:  $ nvm ls-remote"
echo "... and pass the version number you want as the only param to $MY_NAME. $CR"
echo "Are you ready to install the latest version of nvm and npm and node version $NODE_VER_TO_INSTALL ?$CR"
echo "Press CTL+C to exit --or-- Enter to continue..."
read x

echo """$REV""Uninstalling nvm...$CR$OFF"
# Making backups, but in all likelyhood you'll just reinstall them (and won't need these backups)
if [ ! -d "$BACKUP_DIR" ]; then 
    echo "Creating directory to store $HOME/.nvm .npm and .bower cache backups: $BACKUP_DIR"
    mkdir -p $BACKUP_DIR
fi 
set -x
mv $HOME/.nvm   $BACKUP_DIR  2>/dev/null
mv $HOME/.npm   $BACKUP_DIR  2>/dev/null
mv $HOME/.bower $BACKUP_DIR  2>/dev/null
{ set +x; } &>/dev/null

echo "$REV""$CR""Uninstalling node...$CR$OFF"
echo "Enter your password to remove user some node-related /usr/local directories"
set -x
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node
rm -rf /usr/local/include/node
rm -rf /usr/local/include/node_modules
rm /usr/local/bin/npm
rm /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d
rm -rf $HOME/.node
rm -rf $HOME/.node-gyp
rm /opt/local/bin/node
rm /opt/local/include/node
rm -rf /opt/local/lib/node_modules
rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar/nvm
brew uninstall node 2>/dev/null
{ set +x; } &>/dev/null

echo "$REV""$CR""Installing nvm...$CR$OFF"

echo "++brew install nvm"
brew install nvm 
echo '$(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh'
source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh

echo "$REV""$CR""Insert the following line in your startup script (ex: $HOME/.bashrc):$CR$OFF"
echo "export NVM_DIR=\"\$(brew --prefix nvm)\"; [ -s \"\$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh\" ] && . \"\$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh\"$CR"
NVM_DIR="$(brew --prefix nvm)"

echo """$CR""Using nvm install node...$CR"
echo "++ nvm install $NODE_VER_TO_INSTALL"
nvm install $NODE_VER_TO_INSTALL
NODE_BINARY_PATH="`find /usr/local/Cellar/nvm -name node -type d|head -n 1`/$NODE_VER_TO_INSTALL/bin"
echo "$REV""$CR""Insert the following line in your startup script (ex: $HOME/.bashrc) and then restart your shell:$CR$OFF"
echo "export PATH=\$PATH:$NODE_BINARY_PATH:$HOME/.node/bin"

echo """$CR""Upgrading npm...$CR"
echo '++ install -g npm@latest'
npm install -g npm@latest
{ set +x; } &>/dev/null
echo "$REV""$CR""Insert following line in your $HOME/.npmrc file:$OFF"
echo """$CR""prefix=$HOME/.node$CR"
echo "Now, all is likley well if you can run the following without errors:  npm install -g grunt-cli$CR"
echo "Other recommended global installs: bower, gulp, yo, node-inspector$CR"
```

I wrote a short article [here](http://lexsheehan.blogspot.com/2015/04/cleanly-install-nvm-node-and-npm.html) that details why this is "the right way".

If you need to install iojs, do so using nvm like this:

```
nvm install iojs-v1.7.1
```

To install brew, just see its [home page](http://brew.sh/).

See alexpods answer for the rest.

Comment: Awesome to see that all these package managers and version managers really help to remove custom written scripts, hacks, and workarounds to get techstack xyz working. awesome.

Comment: Worked for me even though I started with npm and brew both broken

Answer (score 5):

You should install node.js with nvm, because that way you do not have to provide superuser privileges when installing global packages (you can simply execute "npm install -g packagename" without prepending 'sudo').

Brew is fantastic for other things, however. I tend to be biased towards Bower whenever I have the option to install something with Bower.

Comment: Installing node using nvm is now my preferred approach. For the obvious reason of being able to have multiple versions of node on my machine and also I don't have to execute npm with sudo . I wrote a blog post http://garywoodfine.com/install-nodejs-nvm-osx/ explaining how to install

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I do:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.20.0/install.sh | bash
cd / && . ~/.nvm/nvm.sh && nvm install 0.10.35
. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh && nvm alias default 0.10.35
```

No Homebrew for this one.

`nvm` soon will support io.js, but not at time of posting: https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/590

Then install everything else, per-project, with a `package.json` and `npm install`.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with noa -- if you need to have multiple versions of `node`, `io.js` then brew is not the appropriate solution.

You can help beta-test `io.js` support in nvm: https://github.com/creationix/nvm/pull/616

If you just want `io.js` and are not switching versions, then you can install the binary distribution of `io.js` from https://iojs.org/dist/v1.0.2/iojs-v1.0.2-darwin-x64.tar.gz ; that includes `npm` and you will not need `nvm` if you are not switching versions.

Remember to update `npm` after installing: `sudo npm install -g npm@latest`

Answer (score 1):

For install with zsh and Homebrew:

```
brew install nvm  <=== This is not recommended by NVM. They want to run their shell script instead

curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
```

Then Add the following to ~/.zshrc or your desired shell
configuration file:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
. "/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh"
```

Then install a node version and use it.

```
nvm install 7.10.1
nvm use 7.10.1
```

Comment: from this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/41913355/773322
"You shouldn't have a package manager managing a package manager". Consider deleting your answer.

Comment: interesting, I didn't know that myself. I have been using brew to install NVM for the last 10 years and didn't really have an issue. But if I was going to setup a new machine today I would use their script.

Comment: "nvm use" resolved my issue

Answer (score 0):

**2021 Update**

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.37.2/install.sh | bash
```

Troubleshooting for MAC:

Since macOS 10.15, the default shell is zsh and nvm will look for .zshrc to update, none is installed by default. Create one with touch ~/.zshrc and run the install script again.

If you use bash, the previous default shell, run touch ~/.bash_profile to create the necessary profile file if it does not exist.

You might need to restart your terminal instance or run . ~/.nvm/nvm.sh. Restarting your terminal/opening a new tab/window, or running the source command will load the command and the new configuration.

You have previously used bash, but you have zsh installed. You need to manually add these lines to ~/.zshrc and run . ~/.zshrc.