# Install io.js and npm without node via Homebrew on OSX

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, homebrew, io.js

As $title says, I want to install io.js with brew on Yosemite.
In my system there is no need for Node.js, and I want to avoid unnecessary programs.

But..  When I run `brew install iojs` I see it will be built with `--without-npm` option, and as the post-install text clarifies, it needs a *patched npm*.

Although I searched for the solution, the only thing that came across is how to run io.js and Node.js side-by-side, and that's not what I'm looking for.

I see there is an npm package for brew, but it's part of the node package.

How can I install iojs+npm without node?

Answer (score 3):

1. Install [`nvm`](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) (node version manager) using `brew`:

   ```
   brew update
   brew install nvm
   source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh
   ```

   Add the last command to the `.profile`, `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` file to not run it again on every terminal start. So for example to add it to the `.profile` run:

   ```
   echo "source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh" >> ~/.profile
   ```
2. Using `nvm` you can install any version of `node` or `io.js` you want. So to install the latest version of `iojs` do:

   ```
   nvm install iojs
   ```

`npm` is shipping with `iojs` so you don't need to install it manually.

Related question: [What is the suggested way to install brew, node.js, io.js, nvm, npm on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28017374/what-is-the-suggested-way-to-install-brew-node-js-io-js-nvm-npm-on-os-x)

Comment: `nvm` is an other thing I want to avoid. `brew` is fully capable to get and update the latest version of `iojs`. I don't want to maintain, manually update and then configure to be the default version of `iojs`.

it's just a plus abstraction level for me, nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem: homebrew doesn't seem to properly explain how to get that "patched" npm in a clean way.

Anyway, nothing has worked for me better than getting that `pkg` from [iojs.org](https://iojs.org), which includes npm.

(I'm referring to `iojs` v2.0.0)

Answer (score 1):

It might be late but you can just use `brew unlink node && brew link iojs --force`
I avoided nvm because it was way too slow for me