# The best way to install node.js on a Mac?

Tags: node.js, macos

Homebrew and the Node download page install node.js in different locations that apparently conflict. Brew will complain after a 'brew doctor' if both locations are used.

So, is there a preferred way to put node on my Mac(Yosemite 10.10.5).

This is what I'm getting now while attempting to install node via brew.

```
node-4.1.0 already installed, it's just not linked
DONs-iMac:Erlang-Elixir donfox1$ brew link node
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/4.1.0... 
Error: Could not symlink share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp
/usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset is not writable.
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried chmoding 755 /usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset so it is writable? That could fix it?

```
chmod 755 /usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset
brew link node
```

Also try this if it does not work (may work):

```
brew cleanup
brew link node
brew uninstall node
brew install node
```

Comment: I did the above and still have the same issue. The permissions  on tapes, an empty directory is: **drwxr-xr-x  2 root  admin  68 Sep 21 16:00 tapset**.   Still it is unwritable?

Comment: Okay then do chmod 777 and revert back to 755 once it's done the install.

Comment: Remove folder `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/systemtap/`, uninstall node `brew uninstall node`, reinstall node `brew install node`, create symlinks `brew link node`

Answer (score 1):

`sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/share/ 
 brew doctor 
 brew install node`

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall node:
`sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/systemtap/ && brew uninstall node` 
and install nvm with brew - so you can control you node versions.
Read this article: [suggested way to install npm with brew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28017374/what-is-the-suggested-way-to-install-brew-node-js-io-js-nvm-npm-on-os-x)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure about what version of node you need now and potentially need in the future I would also reccomend to install NVM - node version manager.
Download the nvm install script via cURL:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.0/install.sh | bash
```

Ensure that nvm was installed correctly with `nvm --version`, which should return the version of nvm installed.
Install the version of Node.js you want
Install the latest version with `nvm install node`
Use the latest version with `nvm use node`
Install the latest LTS version with `nvm install --lts`
Use the latest LTS verison with `nvm use --lts`

You can also check the tutorials:
[installing-node-js-tutorial-using-nvm-on-mac-os-x-and-ubuntu](https://nodesource.com/blog/installing-node-js-tutorial-using-nvm-on-mac-os-x-and-ubuntu/)
[Best way to install and use nvm on Mac](https://medium.com/@isaacjoe/best-way-to-install-and-use-nvm-on-mac-e3a3f6bc494d)