# Can't uninstall npm module on OSX

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

I have installed cordova on my mac and want to uninstall it.

I've tried the following:

```
npm uninstall cordova -g
```

but I get the following error:

```
npm WARN uninstall not installed in /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.32/lib/node_modules: "cordova"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: did you install it with `homebrew`?

Comment: I don't think so. I get: "Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/cordova" if I try "brew uninstall cordova -g"

Comment: but did you install `node` with homebrew?

Comment: Probably, not sure. I'm not too familiar with the terminal. I installed this a year ago by just following some guide. How can I check what you're asking?

Comment: Take a look at this https://gist.github.com/DanHerbert/9520689

Comment: Your node version is fairly out of date now - if that version doesn't matter then upgrade to v4 following the installation instructions here https://nodejs.org/en/

Comment: Make sure you get v4.1.2 which fixes a critical security issue

Comment: Allright. Will try. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are know issues with the way `homebrew` and `npm` play together. From [this article by Dan Herbert](https://gist.github.com/DanHerbert/9520689)

> There's an [NPM bug](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3794) for this exact problem. The bug has been "fixed" by
>   Homebrew installing npm in a way that allows it to manage itself once
>   the install is complete. However, this is error-prone and still seems
>   to cause problems for some people. The root of the the issue is really
>   that npm is its own package manager and it is therefore better to have
>   npm manage itself and its packages completely on its own instead of
>   letting Homebrew do it.

Aside from that your node version is out of date. If you can upgrade you should do so to Node v4.1.2. Follow the instructions on the [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) site.