# Node process.env.VARIABLE_NAME returning undefined

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

I'm using environment variables on my mac to store some sensitive credentials, and trying to access them through Node. I added them into my environment profile with

`export VARIABLE_NAME=mySensitiveInfo`

When I use `echo $VARIABLE_NAME` I receive the correct output (my sensitive info).

However, when I am trying to access this same variable in Node with `process.env.VARIABLE_NAME` and try to print it out on the console, I get an undefined.

Other environment variables appear to be okay though. For example, when I `console.log(process.env.FACEBOOK_CALLBACK_URL)`, it prints the correct value to my console. I added **FACEBOOK_CALLBACK_URL** a few days ago.

Do I have to restart my machine or something? Does it take a certain time before environment variables become available in Node? The closest answer I've seen on SO is [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33737660/process-env-variables-are-undefined-even-after-export), but nobody was able to figure out why it was happening.

Comment: What is the environment profile? `.bash_profile`?

Comment: How are you running the Node program?

Comment: @JeremyRodi I'm using Visual Studio Code and using `nodemon` or `node app.js` to start my program.

Comment: @shaochuancs I actually added both `.profile` and `.bash_profile` after `.bash_profile` wasn't working. So right now I have both.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`process.env.VARIABLE_NAME` returns `undefined` because the Node.js execution environment does not know the newly added `VARIABLE_NAME` yet. To fix the issue, the Node.js execution environment (e.g. IDE) need to restart.

The following steps can be used to reproduce this issue:

1. Open IDE such as WebStorm and write a simple Node.js program: `console.log(process.env.VARIABLE_NAME)`. It will print `undefined` as expected, as `VARIABLE_NAME` is not defined yet. Keep the IDE running, don't close it.
2. Open environment profile such as `.bash_profile` and add `export VARIABLE_NAME=mySensitiveInfo` in it.
3. Open system console and run `source .bash_profile`, so that the above `export` statement will be executed. From now on, whenever system console is opened, `VARIABLE_NAME` environment variable exists.
4. In system console, execute the Node.js program in step 1, it will print `mySensitiveInfo`.
5. Switch to IDE and execute Node.js program, it will print `undefined`.
6. Restart the IDE and execute Node.js program, this time, it will print `mySensitiveInfo`

Comment: just cancel the npm run watch and run again npm run watch and its working

Comment: Restarting the IDE took care of my issue - thank you!

Comment: what if the variable needs to be added to the local terminal process only. How does that work, if we restart that IDE the variables would get lost anyway

Comment: Then I think the variable can be defined in the local terminal. After the IDE is closed (local terminal exit), that variable would disappear.

Answer (score 61):

`nodemon.json` file is only for setting nodemon specific configuration
So for create custom environment variables we can use dotenv package

First , Install dotenv package

```
npm install dotenv --save
```

after that create .env file in root and include environment variables as bellows

```
MONGO_ATLAS_PW=xxxxx
JWT_KEY=secret
```

Finally, inside your `app.js` file  insert following after your imports.

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

Then you can use environment varibale like this

```
process.env.MONGO_ATLAS_PW
process.env.JWT_KEY
```

Comment: this straightforwardly worked for me. thanks.

Comment: Note:- By "after that create .env file in root" OP means that you have to create the .env file in the same folder where you have your package.json.                                                              This worked for me :)

Comment: Note: when sending .env files over discord the "." drops off leaving an "env" file. Make sure there is a dot at the start! Also I wouldn't recommend sending over discord anyway. try usb or other secure methods

Comment: Well, absolutely thanks for the exact answer. works like a charm

Answer (score 22):

For everyone who might have this issue in the future and none of the solutions above are working, it may also be because you're running the `node <filename>.js` in a subfolder or subdirectory, and since your `.env` file is in the root folder, `processs.env.<variable>` will always return undefined.

A simple way to check is to try the following code

```
const test = require('dotenv').config()
console.log(test)
```

In the console we get the following error

```
{   error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\vxcbv\Desktop\voisascript-auth\model\.env'
      at Object.openSync (node:fs:585:3)
      at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:453:35)
      at Object.config (C:\Users\vxcbv\Desktop\voisascript-auth\node_modules\dotenv\lib\main.js:72:42)
      at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\vxcbv\Desktop\voisascript-auth\model\db.js:1:32)
      at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
      at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
      at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
      at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
      at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
      at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
    errno: -4058,
    syscall: 'open',
    code: 'ENOENT',
    path: 'C:\\Users\\vxcbv\\Desktop\\voisascript-auth\\model\\.env'   } }
```

Emphasis on the `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open`.
To solve this, just navigate back to the root and run the file from there, but specify the full path of the file from the root, like 
`node /<subfolder>/<file.js>`

Comment: TYTY (= (= (= (=

Comment: Thanks I was running the script from task manager this solve it
require('dotenv').config({path:'complete_path/.env'})

Comment: This is the only answer that has worked. Heads Up!!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. In my case the env file and db.js was inside a subfolder configs.

So, in index/server.js , while importing the dotven , I used

```
require('dotenv').config({path: './configs/.env'});
```

This way my env variables were being accessed.

Hope this example of mine helps you!

Comment: This is the best answer for 'undefined' variable problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

For anyone stuck in React.

This [article](https://medium.com/@zak786khan/env-variables-undefined-78cf218dae87) helped me to understand .env in React:

> The variable must have a prefix of ‘‘REACT_APP_’’ otherwise the variable will not work properly.

In your .env file, it should look something like this:

```
REACT_APP_YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME=SOMETHING
```

And **NOT** this (what I had and gave undefined):

```
MY_VARIABLE_NAME=SOMETHING
```

Comment: Thank you! I have a vue app in which the `VUE_APP_SOMEVARIABLE` variable got through, but the rest was omitted. I had completely forgotten about the `VUE_APP_` prefix requirement.

Answer (score 4):

I got a problem just now , and I use this solved it in webpack config

```
const plugins = [
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    // after compile global will defined `process.env` this Object
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      BUILD_AT : Date.now().toString(32),
      DEBUG: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
          'process.env': {
              'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || "development"),
              'VARIABLE_NAME': JSON.stringify(process.env.VARIABLE_NAME)
     }
   })
]
```

Answer (score 4):

please check the dir of .env file, If it is in same file as your app.js or (abc.js) than move .env to one level up

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This was my exact problem. I had both the .env and my server root file in the same directory. Moved the .env file up to the parent directory and problem solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Close the code Runner Or Ide environment once and reopen it.
If you use VS code, close it completely. (Or CMD or Power Shell or ...)

Answer (score 0):

While accessing `.env` variables with `dotenv.config()`, The function which was accessing them was called before the dotenv.config().

Before ❌

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
authController.insertAdmin();
dotenv.config();
```

After ✅

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();
authController.insertAdmin();
```

Comment: Just do `require("dotenv").config()`, all at the same time

Answer (score 0):

In my case I missed to prefix the file name with a dot. It took me sometime to figure it out as it was difficult spot.

The file was named as "env.development" instead of ".env.development".