# process.env can't find terminal environmental variables when running IOS/Android

Tags: react-native, babeljs, .env

Variables defined in .env file are not showing up in process.env (in `babel.config.js` as well as in `index.tsx`)

`.env`:

```
ENV_VAR1=testabc
ENV_VAR2=testdef
```

`babel.config`:

```
console.log(process.env);
module.exports = {
....
```

Terminal:

```
user@Users-MacBook-Pro react_frontend % yarn start --reset-cache   
warning:  Obfuscation SKIPPED [Not a *bundle* command]

                        ▒▒▓▓▓▓▒▒
                     ▒▓▓▓▒▒░░▒▒▓▓▓▒
                  ▒▓▓▓▓░░░▒▒▒▒░░░▓▓▓▓▒
                 ▓▓▒▒▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▒▒▒▓▓
                 ▓▓░░░░░▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▒░░░░░▓▓
                 ▓▓░░▓▓▒░░░▒▒░░░▒▓▒░░▓▓
                 ▓▓░░▓▓▓▓▓▒▒▒▒▓▓▓▓▒░░▓▓
                 ▓▓░░▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▒░░▓▓
                 ▓▓▒░░▒▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▒░░░▒▓▓
                  ▒▓▓▓▒░░░▒▓▓▒░░░▒▓▓▓▒
                     ▒▓▓▓▒░░░░▒▓▓▓▒
                        ▒▒▓▓▓▓▒▒


warning: the transform cache was reset.
                Welcome to Metro v0.72.3
              Fast - Scalable - Integrated



To reload the app press "r"
To open developer menu press "d"
user@Users-MacBook-Pro react_frontend % source .env && echo $ENV_VAR1 && npx react-native run-android
testabc
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...
```

Metro terminal:

```
...
transform[stdout]: {
transform[stdout]:   MANPATH: '/opt/homebrew/share/man::',
transform[stdout]:   rvm_bin_path: '/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/bin',
transform[stdout]:   VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_SCRIPT: '/opt/homebrew/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh',
transform[stdout]:   VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PROJECT_FILENAME: '.project',
transform[stdout]:   TERM_PROGRAM: 'Apple_Terminal',
transform[stdout]:   GEM_HOME: '/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0',
transform[stdout]:   ANDROID_HOME: '/Users/xxxxx/Library/Android/sdk',
transform[stdout]:   SHELL: '/bin/zsh',
transform[stdout]:   TERM: 'xterm-256color',
transform[stdout]:   IRBRC: '/Users/xxxxxxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/.irbrc',
transform[stdout]:   HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY: '/opt/homebrew',
transform[stdout]:   TMPDIR: '/var/folders/nq/_9bt81g17cj0036184j_gxrw0000gn/T/',
transform[stdout]:   TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION: '447',
transform[stdout]:   MY_RUBY_HOME: '/Users/xxxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0',
transform[stdout]:   TERM_SESSION_ID: 'xxxxxx',
transform[stdout]:   JENV_FORCEJAVAHOME: 'true',
transform[stdout]:   USER: 'xxxxx',
transform[stdout]:   rvm_path: '/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm',
transform[stdout]:   SSH_AUTH_SOCK: '/xxxxxx',
transform[stdout]:   PODS_ROOT: '/xxxxx/node_modules/react-native/scripts/../../../ios/Pods',
transform[stdout]:   WORKON_HOME: '/Users/xxxxx/.virtualenvs',
transform[stdout]:   rvm_prefix: '/Users/xxxxxx',
transform[stdout]:   VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON: '/opt/homebrew/bin/python3.10',
transform[stdout]:   PATH: 'xxxxxxx',
transform[stdout]:   VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_HOOK_DIR: '/Users/xxxxxx/.virtualenvs',
transform[stdout]:   __CFBundleIdentifier: 'com.apple.Terminal',
transform[stdout]:   JENV_LOADED: '1',
transform[stdout]:   PWD: '/Users/xxxx/Desktop/xxxx/xxxx/xxxxx',
transform[stdout]:   JAVA_HOME: '/Users/xxxxx/.jenv/versions/11.0.17',
transform[stdout]:   XPC_FLAGS: '0x0',
transform[stdout]:   VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV: '/opt/homebrew/bin/virtualenv',
transform[stdout]:   RCT_METRO_PORT: '8081',
transform[stdout]:   JENV_FORCEJDKHOME: 'true',
transform[stdout]:   XPC_SERVICE_NAME: 'xxxxx',
transform[stdout]:   rvm_version: '1.29.12 (latest)',
transform[stdout]:   JDK_HOME: '/Users/xxxxx/.jenv/versions/11.0.17',
transform[stdout]:   SHLVL: '2',
transform[stdout]:   HOME: '/Users/xxxxxx',
transform[stdout]:   HOMEBREW_PREFIX: '/opt/homebrew',
transform[stdout]:   LOGNAME: 'xxxxxxx',
transform[stdout]:   JENV_SHELL: 'zsh',
transform[stdout]:   LC_CTYPE: 'UTF-8',
transform[stdout]:   GEM_PATH: '/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0:/Users/xxxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@global',
transform[stdout]:   NODE_BINARY: '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/19.4.0_1/bin/node',
transform[stdout]:   VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_WORKON_CD: '1',
transform[stdout]:   INFOPATH: '/opt/homebrew/share/info:',
transform[stdout]:   HOMEBREW_CELLAR: '/opt/homebrew/Cellar',
transform[stdout]:   RUBY_VERSION: 'ruby-3.0.0',
transform[stdout]:   OLDPWD: '/Users/xxxx',
transform[stdout]:   _: '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/19.4.0_1/bin/node',
transform[stdout]:   __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING: 'xxxxxx',
transform[stdout]:   FORCE_COLOR: '1',
transform[stdout]:   BABEL_ENV: 'xxxxxx'
transform[stdout]: }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fix:

`yarn add dotenv --dev`

`babel.config` file:

```
require('dotenv').config();
console.log(process.env);
module.exports = {
....
```

answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61442921/9611924