# Remove Node installed via homebrew, replace it by nvm - what is the best way?

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, homebrew, nvm

I installed Node via homebrew a couple of weeks ago.

I know need to install nvm to run older versions of Node. To do so, I need to uninstall my current Node.

If I run:

```
$ brew uninstall node
```

I understand that I will uninstall npm and Node.

But since I installed Node, I have installed many packages via npm.

Will running

```
 $ brew uninstall node
```

and then installing nvm via homebrew, and then reinstalling node and npm via nvm break anything in the other packages installed via npm in the last weeks?

Comment: Nvm actually just deals where the pointer for node is for the command line. So you can have several versions of node with different npm packages. You should be able to just download nvm, and then redownload whatever npm packages you need

Comment: This is where my npm modules live currently:
~/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/bin/npm

Comment: If anyone comes to read my question, please make sure to check the following posts on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28017374/what-is-the-suggested-way-to-install-brew-node-js-io-js-nvm-npm-on-os-x and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x

Answer (score 0):

Run this command `nvm use 14.20.1`(your node version you want to use)