# warn Error on lookup for github:systemjs/systemjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, jspm

When I am setting my jspm installation with the command:

```
jspm init
```

Then it just asks me for the initial config:

```
Would you like jspm to prefix the jspm package.json properties under jspm? [yes]:yes

Enter server baseURL (public folder path) [./]:app
Enter jspm packages folder [app/jspm_packages]:
Enter config file path [app/config.js]:
Configuration file app/config.js doesn't exist, create it? [yes]:yes
Enter client baseURL (public folder URL) [/]:
Do you wish to use a transpiler? [yes]:no
```

Right after that, I am getting this error message:

> warn Error on lookup for github:systemjs/systemjs
>        TypeError: "timeout" must be an unsigned integer
>            at validateTimeout (child_process.js:612:11)
>            at Object.exports.execFile (child_process.js:178:3)
>            at exports.exec (child_process.js:136:18)
>            at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jspm/node_modules/jspm-github/exec-git.js:64:5)
>            at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jspm/node_modules/jspm-github/github.js:382:7
>            at initializePromise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jspm/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:588:5)
>            at new Promise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jspm/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1076:31)
>            at GithubLocation.lookup (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jspm/node_modules/jspm-github/github.js:381:12)
>            at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jspm/lib/registry.js:117:30
>            at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jspm/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:538:12)
>            at invokeCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jspm/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:553:13)
>            at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jspm/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:628:16
>            at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jspm/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:2373:5)
>            at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
>            at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
>
> err
>
> err  Error downloading loader files.
>
> err

Not sure what is happening right there. So I came here for some clues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying too much to find was going on. I came with, it  was happening that Jspm had no problems but my Node and Npm version were a pre-release (it seems like this affects the Jspm registry). I was using NodeJs 8.0.0. Anyway if someone stucks on the same, he/she should know that going back to

> node v6.10.3 (npm v3.10.10) versions

fix this little inconvenient.

Works for me, the below commands:

```
brew update
brew install nvm
source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh (adding to ~/.profile)

nvm install 6.10.3
```

For more information [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28017374/what-is-the-suggested-way-to-install-brew-node-js-io-js-nvm-npm-on-os-x) is an excellent post about it