# Reinstall node using nvm on OS X without removing node_modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, ember-cli, nvm

Following the [latest advice](https://yoember.com/nodejs/the-best-way-to-install-node-js/) I decided to remove a previous working Homebrew node install and use [nvm to install node](https://nodesource.com/blog/installing-node-js-tutorial-using-nvm-on-mac-os-x-and-ubuntu/) instead, and also set things up to avoid using sudo.

However, before going further

I carefully cleaned out the following folder (owned by my user) except for two modules used for a long-standing Ember project that uses an older version of node (because I'm not confident of reinstalling the required version of them later):

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/
  bower
  ember-cli
```

If I keep the existing /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ folder with the versions of bower and ember-cli, will this cause any issue on installing nvm and then the node versions I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### NVM uses separate node_modules folder

Talking to myself here, but after leaving the question open for 15+ hours I just went ahead and (following the nvm guide on GitHub) [installed nvm with curl](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/tree/v0.34.0#installation), the latest Long Term Support (LTS) node with `nvm install --lts`

Previously, I was using [n to manage node versions](https://github.com/tj/n), but NVM stores node_modules in a directory determined by the version of node you're currently using, which you can find with `npm root -g` e.g. `~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules`

So, the **previous node_modules folder** used by n at `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/` is **unused by nvm and can be deleted**. After a thorough clean-out and `brew uninstall` of all the previous node installation there were **no issues with new nvm install**, and I now have to **reinstall the previous node modules** stored there.