# Trying to build legacy node/angular/ionic application, failing on node-gyp command

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, ionic-framework, node-gyp

I am trying to build an old application angular/ionic but seems to only fail on the node-gyp sass command.  What can I do?

Here is the package.json:

```
    {
  "name": "ccc",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "export SASS_BINARY_SITE=http://local.com:8081/repository/npm-local/sass/node-sass/releases/download",
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build browser",
    "copy": "ionic-app-scripts copy",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build --prod",
    "ionic:serve": "concurrently --kill-others \"ionic-app-scripts serve --nobrowser\" ",
    "package": "ionic-app-scripts build --minifycss browser"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.10",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "moment": "2.21.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.10",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.7",
    "@types/node": "7.0.15",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.1.3",
    "codelyzer": "4.3.0",
    "concurrently": "^3.4.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.5",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.6.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.1.0",
    "karma": "^1.6.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.3",
    "karma-remap-coverage": "^0.1.4",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^2.0.3",
    "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
    "ts-loader": "4.2.0",
    "ts-node": "6.0.1",
    "tslint": "5.9.1",
    "tslint-loader": "3.6.0",
    "typescript": "2.7.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 6.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3"
  },
  "config": {
    "ionic_copy": "./config/copy.js"
  },
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": {}
    }
  }
}
```

With current build system:

npm -version
8.3.1

node --version
v17.4.0

npm install --force --legacy-peer-deps --unsafe-perm

**Here is the error**

```
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python2
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/SomeUser/git-main5/ccc/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/SomeUser/git-main5/ccc/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/SomeUser/git-main5/ccc/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/SomeUser/.node-gyp/17.4.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/SomeUser/.node-gyp/17.4.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/SomeUser/git-main5/ccc/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/SomeUser/.node-gyp/17.4.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/SomeUser/git-main5/ccc/node_modules/node-sass',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp verb command build []
npm ERR! gyp verb build type Release
npm ERR! gyp verb architecture x64
npm ERR! gyp verb node dev dir /Users/SomeUser/.node-gyp/17.4.0
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded for `make` /usr/bin/make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'V=1', 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/binding.cpp:1:
npm ERR! In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:60:
npm ERR! In file included from /Users/SomeUser/.node-gyp/17.4.0/include/node/node.h:63:
npm ERR! In file included from /Users/SomeUser/.node-gyp/17.4.0/include/node/v8.h:25:
npm ERR! In file included from /Users/SomeUser/.node-gyp/17.4.0/include/node/v8-array-buffer.h:12:
npm ERR! In file included from /Users/SomeUser/.node-gyp/17.4.0/include/node/v8-local-handle.h:12:
npm ERR! /Users/SomeUser/.node-gyp/17.4.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:563:38: error: no template named 'remove_cv_t' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'remove_cv'?
npm ERR!             !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
npm ERR!                                 ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR!                                      remove_cv
npm ERR! /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/type_traits:660:50: note: 'remove_cv' declared here
npm ERR! template <class _Tp> struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS remove_cv
npm ERR!                                                  ^
npm ERR! ../src/binding.cpp:248:30: warning: 'Call' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
npm ERR!     ctx_w->success_callback->Call(0, 0);
npm ERR!                              ^
npm ERR! ../../nan/nan.h:1745:3: note: 'Call' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
npm ERR!   NAN_DEPRECATED inline v8::Local<v8::Value>
npm ERR!   ^
npm ERR! ../../nan/nan.h:110:40: note: expanded from macro 'NAN_DEPRECATED'
npm ERR! # define NAN_DEPRECATED __attribute__((deprecated))
npm ERR!                                        ^
npm ERR! ../src/binding.cpp:256:28: warning: 'Call' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
npm ERR!     ctx_w->error_callback->Call(1, argv);
npm ERR!                            ^
npm ERR! ../../nan/nan.h:1745:3: note: 'Call' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
npm ERR!   NAN_DEPRECATED inline v8::Local<v8::Value>
npm ERR!   ^
npm ERR! ../../nan/nan.h:110:40: note: expanded from macro 'NAN_DEPRECATED'
npm ERR! # define NAN_DEPRECATED __attribute__((deprecated))
npm ERR!                                        ^
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/binding.cpp:3:
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/sass_context_wrapper.h:9:
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/custom_function_bridge.h:7:
npm ERR! ../src/callback_bridge.h:162:21: warning: 'Call' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
npm ERR!   bridge->callback->Call(argv_v8.size(), &argv_v8[0]);
npm ERR!                     ^
npm ERR! ../src/callback_bridge.h:68:65: note: in instantiation of member function 'CallbackBridge<Sass_Value *, void *>::dispatched_async_uv_callback' requested here
npm ERR!     uv_async_init(uv_default_loop(), this->async, (uv_async_cb) dispatched_async_uv_callback);
npm ERR!                                                                 ^
npm ERR! ../src/custom_function_bridge.h:11:70: note: in instantiation of member function 'CallbackBridge<Sass_Value *, void *>::CallbackBridge' requested here
npm ERR!     CustomFunctionBridge(v8::Local<v8::Function> cb, bool is_sync) : CallbackBridge<Sass_Value*>(cb, is_sync) {}
npm ERR!                                                                      ^
npm ERR! ../../nan/nan.h:1745:3: note: 'Call' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
npm ERR!   NAN_DEPRECATED inline v8::Local<v8::Value>
npm ERR!   ^
npm ERR! ../../nan/nan.h:110:40: note: expanded from macro 'NAN_DEPRECATED'
npm ERR! # define NAN_DEPRECATED __attribute__((deprecated))
npm ERR!                                        ^
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/binding.cpp:3:
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/sass_context_wrapper.h:9:
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/custom_function_bridge.h:7:
npm ERR! ../src/callback_bridge.h:162:21: warning: 'Call' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
npm ERR!   bridge->callback->Call(argv_v8.size(), &argv_v8[0]);
npm ERR!                     ^
npm ERR! ../src/callback_bridge.h:68:65: note: in instantiation of member function 'CallbackBridge<Sass_Import **, void *>::dispatched_async_uv_callback' requested here
npm ERR!     uv_async_init(uv_default_loop(), this->async, (uv_async_cb) dispatched_async_uv_callback);
npm ERR!                                                                 ^
npm ERR! ../src/custom_importer_bridge.h:13:70: note: in instantiation of member function 'CallbackBridge<Sass_Import **, void *>::CallbackBridge' requested here
npm ERR!     CustomImporterBridge(v8::Local<v8::Function> cb, bool is_sync) : CallbackBridge<SassImportList>(cb, is_sync) {}
npm ERR!                                                                      ^
npm ERR! ../../nan/nan.h:1745:3: note: 'Call' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
npm ERR!   NAN_DEPRECATED inline v8::Local<v8::Value>
npm ERR!   ^
npm ERR! ../../nan/nan.h:110:40: note: expanded from macro 'NAN_DEPRECATED'
npm ERR! # define NAN_DEPRECATED __attribute__((deprecated))
npm ERR!                                        ^
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/binding.cpp:3:
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/sass_context_wrapper.h:9:
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/custom_function_bridge.h:7:
npm ERR! ../src/callback_bridge.h:110:23: warning: 'Call' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
npm ERR!       this->callback->Call(argv_v8.size(), &argv_v8[0])
npm ERR!                       ^
npm ERR! ../src/binding.cpp:19:16: note: in instantiation of member function 'CallbackBridge<Sass_Import **, void *>::operator()' requested here
npm ERR!   return bridge(argv);
npm ERR!                ^
npm ERR! ../../nan/nan.h:1745:3: note: 'Call' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
npm ERR!   NAN_DEPRECATED inline v8::Local<v8::Value>
npm ERR!   ^
npm ERR! ../../nan/nan.h:110:40: note: expanded from macro 'NAN_DEPRECATED'
npm ERR! # define NAN_DEPRECATED __attribute__((deprecated))
npm ERR!                                        ^
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/binding.cpp:3:
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/sass_context_wrapper.h:9:
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/custom_function_bridge.h:7:
npm ERR! ../src/callback_bridge.h:110:23: warning: 'Call' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
npm ERR!       this->callback->Call(argv_v8.size(), &argv_v8[0])
npm ERR!                       ^
npm ERR! ../src/binding.cpp:32:16: note: in instantiation of member function 'CallbackBridge<Sass_Value *, void *>::operator()' requested here
npm ERR!   return bridge(argv);
npm ERR!                ^
npm ERR! ../../nan/nan.h:1745:3: note: 'Call' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
npm ERR!   NAN_DEPRECATED inline v8::Local<v8::Value>
npm ERR!   ^
npm ERR! ../../nan/nan.h:110:40: note: expanded from macro 'NAN_DEPRECATED'
npm ERR! # define NAN_DEPRECATED __attribute__((deprecated))
npm ERR!                                        ^
npm ERR! 6 warnings and 1 error generated.
npm ERR! make: *** [Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/SomeUser/git-main5/ccc/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:520:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/SomeUser/git-main5/ccc/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/SomeUser/git-main5/ccc/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v17.4.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Comment: I think your node version might be the issue here. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60248452/is-there-a-compatibility-list-for-angular-angular-cli-and-node-js/60258560#60258560

Comment: Looks like best may be docker, but still seems to be an issue with node-gyp and may the build tools on my mac system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similiar problems with node-gyp and sass using nodeJS v17.xx. What worked for me was downgrading to nodeJS v16.17. In your case and according to the link in @MikeOne 's comment you might need to downgrade even further.

I am using linux so I will link for linux how to install nodeJS. other OS solutions can be found easily.

install nodeJS in ubuntu:

```
sudo apt update
curl -s https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo bash
sudo apt install nodejs
```

install nodeJS in ArchLinux:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Node.js#Installation

as I saw in one of your comments you are using macOS, I found this question on how to install nodeJS in macOS: [What is the recommended way to install Node.js, nvm and npm on MacOS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28017374/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-install-node-js-nvm-and-npm-on-macos-x)

you can then confirm your node version with:

```
node -v
```

Comment: That may do it, let me try

Comment: PS: maybe its worth trying out v16 first see if that already works before downgrading further

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with node-gyp and sass

here are my solutions

1. downgrade node version to v14.xX or
2. Install python2 https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.0/ and you env variable or
3. remove node-sass package